# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable folium choropleth plots

Tags: python, folium

Could anyone explain where I'm going wrong here please?  I'm very new to coding.  I'm trying to do a choropleth plot using folium.  I have  csv file with  5 columns of data: "contact_name", "city", "country", "alpha_2_code" and "Count" which I'm importing for plotting using the code below.  I'm requesting a json file with country data with this format (this is the [0] index): {'id': 4, 'name': 'Afghanistan', 'alpha2': 'af', 'alpha3': 'afg'}.

I've tried searching stack overflow for solutions as well as youtube videos and an udemy course I'm working through but I don't *think* I've found anything to fit the bill.

I'm expecting the code below to return a choropleth plot of shaded countries.  My counts column just has a value of 1 for each entry but I want the plot to be darker if, for example, there are multiple country entries but I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15828/2184368914.py in <module>
----> 1 folium.Choropleth(geo_data=geojson,data=map_data,column = ["alpha_2_code","count"],key_on="alpha2",fill_color="BuPu",
      2     fill_opacity=0.7,line_opacity=0.2).add_to(M)

mypath\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
   1198         if hasattr(data, 'set_index'):
   1199             # This is a pd.DataFrame
-> 1200             color_data = data.set_index(columns[0])[columns[1]].to_dict()
   1201         elif hasattr(data, 'to_dict'):
   1202             # This is a pd.Series

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable


import pandas as pd
import requests
import folium
df = pd.read_csv(r"file with some data and a column of alpha_2 country codes.csv")
map_data = df[["Contact_name","City","Country","alpha_2_code","count"]]
geojson_url = ("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stefangabos/world_countries/master/data/en/world.json")
response = requests.get(geojson_url)
geojson = response.json()
M = folium.Map(location = [20,10], zoom_start = 2)
folium.Choropleth(geo_data=geojson,data=map_data,column = ["alpha_2_code","count"],key_on="alpha2",fill_color="BuPu",fill_opacity=0.7,line_opacity=0.2).add_to(M)
```

Comment: Please update the question to include the **entire** error traceback message, not just the final error.

Comment: Hope I've now added the entire error message correctly.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. You should ask yourself why you have `None` at some pointer where something subscriptable (`list`, `str`, `dict` etc) is expected.

Comment: I realised that column in my final line should be column(s).  That stopped the subscriptable error but I'm not getting a keyerror type error.

Comment: Perhaps its because the third argument to the function is named `columns`, but you're passing `column = ...`?

Comment: _That stopped the subscriptable error but I'm not getting a keyerror type error._ If you're not getting an error, then what is the problem...?

Comment: Thanks for responding John.  passing columns rather than column stopped the 'object is not subscriptable error' but I am now getting a "keyerror type error." which I think might be something to do with the 'key_on = "alpha2" statement in the last line of code?